# How to change onhover list show/close in Magento Community

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, navigation

I have a minor problem.

[Left side navigation menu toggle](http://onlinekiosken.nu/) <--- website link - see left category navigation.

As you see in the link above, this is a left side navigation with toggle option. When clicking on the + sign the submenu gets unfolded and the + sign becomes a - sign, when clicking the - sign it gets back to normal.

The title on the left side is a link, when clicking on the title on the left it gets be directly ex. to the Fast Food category. However, I would like the title to have the same option as the +/- sign - and removing the link class.

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="block block-side-nav-container">    
    <div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
    <div class="side-nav">
   <ul id="category-treeview" class="treeview-side treeview">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
        <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I might think that the code is a php language, please see below:

```
    protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
    $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
{
    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = array();

    // get all children
    if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
        $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
        $childrenCount = count($children);
    } else {
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        $childrenCount = $children->count();
    }
    $hasChildren = ($children && $childrenCount);

    // select active children
    $activeChildren = array();
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeChildren[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeChildrenCount = count($activeChildren);
    $hasActiveChildren = ($activeChildrenCount > 0);

    // prepare list item html classes
    $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'level' . $level;
    $classes[] = 'nav-' . $this->_getItemPosition($level);
    if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    $linkClass = '';
    if ($isOutermost && $outermostItemClass) {
        $classes[] = $outermostItemClass;
        $linkClass = ' class="'.$outermostItemClass.'"';
    }
    if ($isFirst) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }
    if ($isLast) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren) {
        $classes[] = 'parent';
    }

    // prepare list item attributes
    $attributes = array();
    if (count($classes) > 0) {
        $attributes['class'] = implode(' ', $classes);
    }
    if ($hasActiveChildren && !$noEventAttributes) {
         $attributes['onmouseover'] = 'toggleMenu(this,1)';
         $attributes['onmouseout'] = 'toggleMenu(this,0)';
    }

    // assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';
    $html[] = $htmlLi;

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';

    // render children
    $htmlChildren = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
        $htmlChildren .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
            $child,
            ($level + 1),
            ($j == $activeChildrenCount - 1),
            ($j == 0),
            false,
            $outermostItemClass,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $noEventAttributes
        );
        $j++;
    }
    if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        }
        $html[] = '<ul class="level' . $level . '">';
        $html[] = $htmlChildren;
        $html[] = '</ul>';
        if ($childrenWrapClass) {
            $html[] = '</div>';
        }
    }

    $html[] = '</li>';

    $html = implode("\n", $html);
    return $html;
}
```

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: do you want the link to do the same thing as clicking on the +/- sign?

Comment: SAMTHEMAN999 - Exactly! Simple as that, the problem is that i cannot find the code to change for that. When using the Google Developer Tools and playing with it i am able to change it (HTML style). But where do I find it on the above written code?

Comment: Did you write all of this code yourself?

Comment: Nope, it is a template for Magento Webshop - using Magento Community.

Comment: well can you get hold of the javascript for this function otherwise I cannot help you

Comment: yes ofc, but is it a javascript code i must look for?

Comment: i might think that the code is somewhere in the above written code, but i cannot figure out where exactly :/

Comment: The PHP code displays the fast food items but there should be another javascript file which runs the functions when the + button is pressed

Comment: Ah okay, i see - well i'll try to find it. Perhaps it is in the custom.js file?

Comment: I don't use magneto myself so I would be sure, but it will probably be in a js file that they have created themselves, not custom

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this with jQuery. 
All you have to do is add a slideToggle function to your menutitle.

1. First be sure to include jQuery in your site
2. Create a js file for little js fixes (i usually call it customjs.js) and include from the footer of your site
3. Add the following jQuery

   $(".block-title").click(function(){
       $(".block-content").slideToggle(); //SLIDE TOGGLE FOR SLIDING UP AND DOWN
       return false; // PREVENTS LINK FROM WORKING
   })

Check jsfiddle.net/pTg68/17/ for an example

Cheerz

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find what the function is called, I would imagine it look something like this:

```
var menu = "closed";

function toggleMenu(){

  if(menu = "closed"){
     openTree();
  }else{
     closeTree();
  } 
}

function openTree(){  
    //code to open the menu
};

function closeTree(){  
   //code to close the menu
};
```

And all you would do is change the link from each category from

```
<a href="fastfood.html">Fast Food</a>
```

**to**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleMenu();">Fast Food</a>
```